# MYSQL: Slow query once the data get larger

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have this long query and the result is taking to long. It can take up to 15 seconds to 20 seconds. In small amount of data the query seems OK, and I have checked all indexes, and everything already using index or where condition.

Sorry, I don't post the actual queries because it is so many and connected to other tables.

Can anyone help? If you need any further information, let me know.

Below is the EXPLAINation from mysql.

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    210326  
2   DERIVED PQL ref practice_place_id,patient_id,practice_place_id_2,encounter_id,practice_place_id_3,for_comission for_comission   4   const   38950   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   
2   DERIVED EN  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,practice_id,practice_id_2,practice_id_3  PRIMARY 8   PQL.encounter_id,const  1   Using index 
2   DERIVED PIH ref PRIMARY,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8    practice_id_3   12  const,EN.id 1   Using index condition; Using where  
2   DERIVED RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PQL.patient_id    1       
2   DERIVED PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   timestamp   12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
2   DERIVED RV  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   PID.item_id 1       
2   DERIVED RRV eq_ref  PRIMARY,parent_id   PRIMARY 8   PID.item_id,PID.item_sub_id 1   Using index 
2   DERIVED D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id   1   Using where 
2   DERIVED RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PIH.timestamp   1   Using where 
2   DERIVED PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
2   DERIVED TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
3   UNION   PQL ref practice_place_id,patient_id,practice_place_id_2,encounter_id,practice_place_id_3,for_comission for_comission   4   const   38950   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   
3   UNION   EN  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,practice_id,practice_id_2,practice_id_3  PRIMARY 8   PQL.encounter_id,const  1   Using index 
3   UNION   PIH ref PRIMARY,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8    practice_id_3   12  const,EN.id 1   Using index condition; Using where  
3   UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PQL.patient_id    1       
3   UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   timestamp   12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
3   UNION   RV  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   PID.item_id 1       
3   UNION   RRV eq_ref  PRIMARY,parent_id   PRIMARY 8   PID.item_id,PID.item_sub_id 1   Using index 
3   UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id_2 1   Using where 
3   UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PIH.timestamp   1   Using where 
3   UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
3   UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
4   UNION   PQL ref practice_place_id,patient_id,practice_place_id_2,encounter_id,practice_place_id_3,for_comission for_comission   4   const   38950   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   
4   UNION   EN  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,practice_id,practice_id_2,practice_id_3  PRIMARY 8   PQL.encounter_id,const  1   Using index 
4   UNION   PIH ref PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 practice_id_3   12  const,EN.id 1   Using index condition; Using where  
4   UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PQL.patient_id    1       
4   UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
4   UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   timestamp   12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
4   UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PIH.timestamp   1   Using where 
4   UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
4   UNION   REF eq_ref  PRIMARY,practice_id,type,id,practice_id_3,id_2  PRIMARY 5   PID.item_id,PID.item_type   1   Using where 
4   UNION   DF  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   REF.form    1   Using where 
4   UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id   1   Using where 
5   UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   practice_id_3   5   const,const 6533    Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
5   UNION   REF eq_ref  PRIMARY,practice_id,id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 4   PID.item_id 1   Using where 
5   UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id   1   Using where 
5   UNION   PIH eq_ref  PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 PRIMARY 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
5   UNION   PQL ref practice_place_id,patient_id,practice_place_id_2,encounter_id,practice_place_id_3,for_comission practice_place_id_2 9   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using index condition; Using where  
5   UNION   EN  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,practice_id,practice_id_2,practice_id_3  PRIMARY 8   PIH.reff_id,const   1   Using where; Using index    
5   UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PQL.patient_id    1       
5   UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PID.timestamp   1   Using where 
5   UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
5   UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
6   UNION   PIH ref PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 practice_id_8   5   const,const 10522   Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort  
6   UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   timestamp   12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
6   UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id   1   Using where 
6   UNION   REF eq_ref  PRIMARY,practice_id,type,id,practice_id_3,id_2  PRIMARY 5   PID.item_id,PID.item_type   1   Using where 
6   UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PIH.timestamp   1   Using where 
6   UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
6   UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using where 
6   UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
7   UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   practice_id_3   5   const,const 6533    Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
7   UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PID.timestamp   1   Using where 
7   UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
7   UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id   1   Using where 
7   UNION   REF eq_ref  PRIMARY,practice_id,id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 4   PID.item_id 1   Using where 
7   UNION   PIH eq_ref  PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 PRIMARY 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
7   UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using where 
7   UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
8   UNION   PQL ref practice_place_id,patient_id,practice_place_id_2,encounter_id,practice_place_id_3,for_comission for_comission   4   const   38950   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   
8   UNION   EN  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,practice_id,practice_id_2,practice_id_3  PRIMARY 8   PQL.encounter_id,const  1   Using index 
8   UNION   PIH ref PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 practice_id_3   12  const,EN.id 1   Using index condition; Using where  
8   UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PQL.patient_id    1       
8   UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
8   UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   timestamp   12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
8   UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PIH.timestamp   1   Using where 
8   UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
8   UNION   REF eq_ref  PRIMARY,practice_id,type,id,practice_id_3,id_2  PRIMARY 5   PID.item_id,PID.item_type   1   Using where 
8   UNION   DF  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   REF.form    1   Using where 
8   UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id_2 1   Using where 
9   UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   practice_id_3   5   const,const 6533    Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
9   UNION   REF eq_ref  PRIMARY,practice_id,id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 4   PID.item_id 1   Using where 
9   UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id_2 1   Using where 
9   UNION   PIH eq_ref  PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 PRIMARY 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
9   UNION   PQL ref practice_place_id,patient_id,practice_place_id_2,encounter_id,practice_place_id_3,for_comission practice_place_id_2 9   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using index condition; Using where  
9   UNION   EN  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,practice_id,practice_id_2,practice_id_3  PRIMARY 8   PIH.reff_id,const   1   Using where; Using index    
9   UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PQL.patient_id    1       
9   UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PID.timestamp   1   Using where 
9   UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
9   UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
10  UNION   PIH ref PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 practice_id_8   5   const,const 10522   Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort  
10  UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   timestamp   12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
10  UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id_2 1   Using where 
10  UNION   REF eq_ref  PRIMARY,practice_id,type,id,practice_id_3,id_2  PRIMARY 5   PID.item_id,PID.item_type   1   Using where 
10  UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PIH.timestamp   1   Using where 
10  UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
10  UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using where 
10  UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PIH.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
11  UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   practice_id_3   5   const,const 6533    Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
11  UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PID.timestamp   1   Using where 
11  UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
11  UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id_2 1   Using where 
11  UNION   REF eq_ref  PRIMARY,practice_id,id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 4   PID.item_id 1   Using where 
11  UNION   PIH eq_ref  PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 PRIMARY 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
11  UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using where 
11  UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
12  UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   practice_id_3   5   const,const 525 Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
12  UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id   1   Using where 
12  UNION   PIH eq_ref  PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 PRIMARY 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 

12  UNION   PQL ref practice_place_id,patient_id,practice_place_id_2,encounter_id,practice_place_id_3,for_comission practice_place_id_2 9   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using index condition; Using where  
12  UNION   EN  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,practice_id,practice_id_2,practice_id_3  PRIMARY 8   PIH.reff_id,const   1   Using where; Using index    
12  UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PQL.patient_id    1       
12  UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PID.timestamp   1   Using where 
12  UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
12  UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
12  UNION   PLD ref PRIMARY,practice_id practice_id 8   const,PID.item_id   3   Using index 
12  UNION   PLI eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY 4   PLD.lab_item_id 1   Using index 
12  UNION   PLC eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   PLD.lab_cat_id  1       
13  UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   practice_id_3   5   const,const 525 Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
13  UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id   1   Using where 
13  UNION   PIH eq_ref  PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 PRIMARY 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
13  UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using where 
13  UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PID.timestamp   1   Using where 
13  UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
13  UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
13  UNION   PLD ref PRIMARY,practice_id PRIMARY 4   PID.item_id 4   Using where 
13  UNION   PLI eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY 4   PLD.lab_item_id 1   Using index 
13  UNION   PLC eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   PLD.lab_cat_id  1       
14  UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   practice_id_3   5   const,const 525 Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
14  UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id_2 1   Using where 
14  UNION   PIH eq_ref  PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 PRIMARY 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
14  UNION   PQL ref practice_place_id,patient_id,practice_place_id_2,encounter_id,practice_place_id_3,for_comission practice_place_id_2 9   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using index condition; Using where  
14  UNION   EN  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,practice_id,practice_id_2,practice_id_3  PRIMARY 8   PIH.reff_id,const   1   Using where; Using index    
14  UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PQL.patient_id    1       
14  UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PID.timestamp   1   Using where 
14  UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
14  UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
14  UNION   PLD ref PRIMARY,practice_id practice_id 8   const,PID.item_id   3   Using index 
14  UNION   PLI eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY 4   PLD.lab_item_id 1   Using index 
14  UNION   PLC eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   PLD.lab_cat_id  1       
15  UNION   PID ref item_type,timestamp,practice_id,item_id_2,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3   practice_id_3   5   const,const 525 Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
15  UNION   D   ref doc_id,pp_id,id_2,pp_doc    doc_id  4   PID.doctor_id_2 1   Using where 
15  UNION   PIH eq_ref  PRIMARY,source,reff_id,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8 PRIMARY 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
15  UNION   RPP eq_ref  PRIMARY,patient_id,practice_id,practice_id_2    PRIMARY 8   const,PIH.reff_id   1   Using where 
15  UNION   RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded  timestamp   8   PID.timestamp   1   Using where 
15  UNION   PIC ref practice_id,prc_invoice_detail_id,claim_status,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,practice_id_4,practice_id_5  practice_id 4   const   1   Using where 
15  UNION   TL  ref reff_id reff_id 12  PID.timestamp,const 1   Using where 
15  UNION   PLD ref PRIMARY,practice_id PRIMARY 4   PID.item_id 4   Using where 
15  UNION   PLI eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY 4   PLD.lab_item_id 1   Using index 
15  UNION   PLC eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   PLD.lab_cat_id  1
```

Comment: That's one long EXPLAIN..i will give you a hint check the lines where you see `Using temporary; Using filesort` that combination is MySQL's  performance killer.. I bet it's a GROUP BY/ORDER BY clause that is unproperly indexed.. Optimizing GROUP BY/ORDER BY clause often requires compound indexes (multiple column indexing)

Comment: That is one crazy query. Have fun.

Comment: What tables are you using (what fields do they have) and what it's the required output from the query?

Comment: still checking @RaymondNijland, thanks for the tip. more question: do i need to tune up the one with info Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort in the extra. WHy the extra showing multiple joins?

Comment: That is so hard to read.  Can you get the columns aligned?

Answer (score 0):

"I have checked all indexes, and everything already using index or where condition." -- not good enough.

`Using index condition` *may* mean that a 'composite' index would help.  Let's see some of the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.

Lets's see *one* of the 8-table `UNIONs`.

What version are you using?  Older versions do a terrible job with multiple 'derived' tables -- because there are no indexes.

Does the resultset really have 210K rows?  Or is there a `LIMIT` that we can't see?